# I need to start a timer when my device screen is locked and stop it when the screen is unlocked provided timeout has not occurred

Tags: android

I have a timer which starts if the app goes in background or if the screen gets locked. Unfortunately, the timer is not working when the screen is locked.

Comment: do you want to get how much time does the phone screen is off?

Comment: Please add more information what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: I have an application which has a timer which starts if the app goes in background. Same flow I want to apply if the screen gets locked for 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

For detecting device screen is locked or unlocked You can use this code

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //it is locked
} else {
 //it is not locked
}
```

After that create a thread when device screen is locked for starting a timer. And apply thread.sleep(); when device is unlocked. This might help You..

Comment: In which method should I use this? @Tapan Kumar

Comment: You can use it in OnCreate method